# Ruby Dir.glob mystery: Where are the FNM_xxx flags described?

Tags: ruby

*Note: This has already been posted on [Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6875440) some weeks ago. I'm crossposting it here, because I didn't get any response so far*

Dir.glob provides an optional parameter, usually referred as 'flags'.
Where can I find a documentation about what flags are possible?

The Ruby 2.0 docs just say that the flags are "the same as used in
File.fnmatch".

Looking up the documentation of File.fnmatch, I only find the
explanation that these are the "FNM_xxx" flags, which can be or'ed
together. I could however find no documentation about what FNM_xxx flags
exist.

Where is this described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually defined inside `File::Constants`, and thereby documented under the same.

Look it up with `ri` :

```
ri File::Constants
```

Or read the html doc : [Module: File::Constants (Ruby 2.2.2)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/File/Constants.html).